# What happens to food or ingredients when it expires? How can I preserve them for as long as possible?

Tags: palworld

I've found/gathered/harvested/cooked/bought food/ingredients and they now have a countdown timer on it indicating it'll expire.

What happens to them when they actually expire? What happens to the stack? Does one item in the stack expire? Does the entire stack expire? How can I preserve them as long as possible?

Some observations:

1. Stacks can have separate timers from other stacks of the same type.

   - Combining stacks with different timers will keep the timer of the destination stack.
2. Expiration timer resets when consumed or moved between inventory and storage.
3. Recently cooked foods that haven't been picked up yet doesn't appear to expire. You can't know when it expires until you pick it up, and it's in an "unusable" state.
4. Cake timer is frozen if stored at a Breeding Farm.

I've cooked up tons of food or gotten ingredients and hard to know if/when they're being eaten or whatnot. Cooked up a cake that I don't want to lose until I can make use of it and wondering if it's even worth making as soon as possible or even gathering the ingredients to begin with. Pals assigned to my cooler box are not doing their jobs and I'm losing items...

Comment: At first glance, it seems like only one item in the stack disappears and the counter resets, but I'm looking for more details if any.

Comment: I won't answer because I haven't done the testing myself, but I found a reddit question that asked something similar: https://www.reddit.com/r/Palworld/comments/19cicn2/food_timer/
So I guess anecdotally you have claims that only one food item degrades at a time. As to address the second question in the title, it sound like you can just hit Sort every 15m or so, at least until they fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the timer expires, the stack goes down by one. You can reset it by either eating or transferring to another container.

As for prolonging the timer: Simply put it in a cold box or the refrigerator and have an cooling-capable Pal sit (ie. Jolthog Cryst or Chillet) on it.

There's no way to stop the timer other than being offline or putting cake in the breeding box.

Comment: This might be a bug, but you could just hit sort button in inventory to reset timer as of now.